# carrierwave-video not processing video

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

I am trying to transcode video files and upload them to s3. To do this, I am trying to use the carrierwave-video gem for transcoding. For uploading I am using carrierwave and for background processing I am using carrierwave-backgrounder with a combination of activejob and sidekiq. After transcoding the video file should be uploaded to S3. However, the problem that I've been having is that carrierwave-video is not transcoding video files, but the video files are still being loaded to s3 in the original format. I don't understand where the error is that is causing it not to transcode. Can anyone tell me what I am missing in terms of making carrierwave-video transcode files?

VideoUploader

```
class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  process :set_content_type

  include CarrierWave::Video
  process encode_video: [:mp4, resolution: "640x480", watermark: {}]

  include ::CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  # storage :file
  storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

movie.rb

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
        mount_uploader :video, VideoUploader
        process_in_background :video

        validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 1, maximum: 30 },
                                                                                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
        validates :year, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }
        validates :plot, presence: true, length: { minimum: 1, maximum: 1000 }
        validates :video, presence: true

end
```

movies_controller.rb (create)

```
def create
    movie = Movie.new(movie_params)

                if movie.save
                        VideoProcesserJob.perform_later(movie.id)
                        render json: movie, status: 201
                else
                        render json: { errors: movie.errors }, status: 422
                end
        end
```

VideoProcesserJob.rb

```
class VideoProcesserJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(movie_id)
    movie = Movie.find(movie_id)
  end
end
```